# 'not assignable to type never' after using type predicate

Tags: typescript, datetime

I am trying to combine [a technique for creating strongly typed strings](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/06/19/strongly-typed-date-string-typescript/) with type predicates *but failing*, as the following bit of code shows:
[image]

The error is `TS2339: Property 'substr' does not exist on type 'never'`, but fixing this is exactly what the factory function should have ensured:

```
export function isShortDateTimeWithSpaceDelimiter(
  datetime: string | ShortDateTimeWithSpaceDelimiter
): datetime is ShortDateTimeWithSpaceDelimiter {
  return DateTime.fromFormat(datetime, FORMAT_ISO_DATE_SPACE_DATE_TIME).isValid;
}

export function toShortDateTimeWithSpaceDelimiter(
  datetime: string
): ShortDateTimeWithSpaceDelimiter {
  if (isShortDateTimeWithSpaceDelimiter(datetime)) return datetime;
  throw new TypeError("Not a ShortDateTimeWithSpaceDelimiter");
}
```

Since TS assumes the return type from the factory is `never`, I guess this is not working as I had intended ... What am I missing?

The type definitions look like this:

```
// https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/06/19/strongly-typed-date-string-typescript/
enum LocalDateTimeWithSpaceDelimiterBrand {}

/** Minute granularity: "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm" */
export type ShortDateTimeWithSpaceDelimiter = string & LocalDateTimeWithSpaceDelimiterBrand;
```

Comment: I don't know how that blog post managed to get away with that because `ShortDateTimeWithSpaceDelimiter` is clearly `never`...

Comment: @kellys Well, isn't that the whole point of the type predicate in this case? To say something is `X` that would otherwise never be able to be created?

Comment: I mean to say that TypeScript is not "assuming the return type from the factory is never", it ***is*** never because you have annotated the return type as `ShortDateTime...` which itself is never. Hover over `ShortDateTime...` to see for yourself.

Comment: OK, so there is nothing wrong about the blog there, because he never says you can use `DateStr` as a string. He says you can _pass_ it to any function that accepts a string, which works. So he got his words intact. But that means that if you want to use any functions that accept `DateStr` (or any other string-derived subtype using this technique), you will need to explicitly convert the type to `string` before using it.

Comment: It provides little to no utility because it's *literally* `never`. I think using a typical intersection with a branding property would work better here to serve as nominal typing. (`string & { __ShortDateTimeWithSpaceDelimiter__: unknown }`). But maybe even then this is does not need nominal typing? It is much overhead for little gain anyways 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243291/discussion-between-oligofren-and-kellys).

Answer (score 0):

> It provides little to no utility because it's literally never. I think using a typical intersection with a branding property would work better here to serve as nominal typing. `(string & { __ShortDateTimeWithSpaceDelimiter__: unknown })`. But maybe even then this is does not need nominal typing? It is much overhead for little gain anyways

The type `ShortDateTimeWithSpaceDelimiter` is really just an alias for `never`, so it's practically useless and isn't as helpful as it should be when defining a different "type" of string.

There is also a playground example of nominal typing: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#example/nominal-typing)

So here you could use `string & { __brand: "ShortDateTimeWithSpaceDelimiter" }`.

However I do suggest throwing all of this away altogether and stick with the simple `string`. Why is all of this necessary? Overkill occurs when types start being defined by code and act like code! Types should influence the design and implementation, not the other way around.

Comment: If you want to represent a type that holds a date with no time component, as in the original example, there is no built-in to do that. A string would do fine, but to indicate that a function takes this specifically formatted type of string would not be possible without runtime checks. Having a way of specifying a strict subset of `string` could be useful for such cases. It also helps, as in my case, when you inherit (https://stackoverflow.com/q/71598697) a codebase where the same data field could have any of 3 different string representations, depending on subtype. Then this serves as docs.

Comment: The playground link is great, btw, and explains perfectly when "a string or number can have special context and you don't want to ever make the values transferrable". The links from there to related PRs and articles with tradeoffs were also valuable.

Comment: While I disagree with the assertion that this type of branding of a string is overkill and unnecessary – this answer does show how you can fix the problem the OP was having (where the type ends up being a `never`.

I wrote the blog post referenced at the top of the question, and am in the process of putting out an updated post using the suggested technique for branding: `export type DateStr = string & { __brand: 'DateStr' }`. The original technique worked correctly back in 2017 - but due to changes in TypeScript since then, a different technique is required.