# Super-type has many variations if strongly typed: possible to avoid explosion of subtypes

Tags: typescript

Using [type predicates or type guards](https://dev.to/smeijer/typescript-type-guards-and-type-predicates-4m5e) TS can [infer which of the subtypes of a type union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html) is being used. This works fine for the simple case: `D = A | B | C`, but what about if you start doing subtypes of `U` and want to know if this subtype is an A, B or C? AFAIK I would need to create 3 strongly typed variations of type making up D:

```
U = (A | U | U) & {foo: string}

T = (A | U | U) & {bar: number}
```

If I then need to create a new type `V` that extends (`U | T`), I need to create 2*3 additional types to be able to answer questions such as "This V has the field `bar` and the fields of `A`". This is already unmaintainable, so is there a way I can reduce the explosion of types using generics or some other magic?

I want to be able to refine the type information so that I can know what `x` is without runtime checks (type predicates) when coming across this:

```
function doSomething(x : T|U) {
   // is X of type A, B or C?
   // possible to annotate the types using generics to pass subtype down?
}
```

Right now I have opted to combine the subtypes into Intersection Types for no discernible benefit other than documentation. I do not get type safety that will tell me if `foo?:string` is defined, but I can at least refer to the underlying types for which variations has it defined.

Since I see that it becomes a bit exotic to answer this, I will post an actual type definition dump below to show some actual non-made up type code showing I am not just making up theoretical exercises :)

```
declare namespace Events {
  /**
   * This is the type actually used on the server backend and stored there internally,
   * with the exception of date types, of course
   * See "API v1.pdf" => Calendar and sessions => Event
   */
  export type IEvents = ResponseServerEvent | RequestServerEvent;

  /**
   * Dealing with dates and times is a bit of a mess codewise, but it is essentially local
   * time everywhere, even if you see a `Z` indicating UTC.
   *
   * See the backend:  <code>Event#getFormattedDateByType(datetime)</code>
   * - DATE_FORMAT_DATE = 'Y-m-d'; // Blocked days "2010-12-01"
   * - DATE_FORMAT_TIME = 'H:i\Z'; // Lunch/Availability, ex: "13:00Z"
   * - DATE_FORMAT_DATETIME = 'Y-m-d\TH:i\Z' // everything else: ISO8601 minus second part ...
   */
  type DateOrTimeOrBoth = TimeOnlyWithZ | DateTimeWithZ | DateOnly;

  type BaseEvent = BaseEventBlocked & BaseEventAvailability & BaseEventLunch & BaseEventMin;

  interface BaseEventMin {
    id: string; // Calendar event id
    type: EventType;
    company_id?: string;
  }

  interface BaseEventBlocked extends BaseEventMin {
    start: DateOnly;
    end: DateOnly;
    type: EventType.BlockedDays | EventType.BlockedTime;

    /** description */
    name: string;
  }

  interface BaseEventLunch extends BaseEventMin {
    start: TimeOnlyWithZ;
    end: TimeOnlyWithZ;
    type: EventType.Lunch;
  }

  interface BaseEventAvailability extends BaseEventMin {
    start: TimeOnlyWithZ;
    end: TimeOnlyWithZ;
    type: EventType.Availability;
    name: WeekDay;
  }

  export interface ResponseServerEvent<Session extends Events.SessionFull | Events.SessionPreview>
    extends BaseEvent {
    /** Event creation date, only for events of types AVAILABILITY and LUNCH (see notes below).
     Format: YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ssZ (note the seconds)*/
    created?: DateTimeWithZ;
    timezone?: string | null;
    session?: Session; // only present for type=SESSION
  }

  export interface RequestServerEvent extends BaseEvent {
    session?: SessionRequest; // only present for type=SESSION
  }

  // Lunch
  export interface ILunch extends IEvents {
    type: EventType.Lunch | EventType.LunchPatch | null;
    name: null;
  }

  // Blocked Day
  export interface IBlockedDay extends IEvents {
    type: EventType.BlockedDays | EventType.BlockedTime | null;
  }

  // Schedule
  export interface ISchedule {
    start: string;
    end: string;
    timezone: string;
    created: string;
    name: string;
    is_available: boolean;
    is_blocked: boolean;
    is_full: boolean;
  }

  interface CommonSession {
    id: string;
    notes: string;
    state: "NONE" | "COMPLETED" | "CANCELLED";
    state_reason?: "CLIENT_SICK" | "NO_SHOW" | "TRAINER_NOT_AVAILABLE" | "OTHER"; // reason for CANCELLED state
    state_notes?: string;
    is_editable?: boolean; // not described by api docs
    state_time: string; // Time when state was changed in format YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mmZ
    is_booked: boolean;
  }

  /**
   * From API docs:
   * Depending on response, either Session-Preview or Session-Full response format is used.
   * For requests Session-Base format should be used.
   *
   * Change from Ninestack:
   * - customer is an array
   * - customer_id is an array
   */
  export type ISession = SessionFull | SessionPreview | SessionRequest;

  interface SessionResponse extends CommonSession {
    /** Only if session owner is not current user. */
    owner?: User.IUserPreview;
    customer: User.IUserClient[];
  }

  /** returned by GET /events/{event_id} */
  export interface SessionFull extends SessionResponse {
    workout?: Workouts.IWorkout; // SessionFull
  }

  /** returned by GET /events/ (in the list of Events) */
  export interface SessionPreview extends SessionResponse {
    workout_name?: string; // SessionPreview
    exercises_count?: number; // SessionPreview
  }

  export interface SessionRequest extends CommonSession {
    customer_id?: string[]; // requests only
    workout_id?: UUID; // // requests only
  }

  /**
   * An event from the server. Unclear if this can be assumed to always contain a session object
   * The `session_length` field is only part of `IAgenda` events from the /events/dashboard
   * endpoint, so a little unclear how/when/why this is used, as it should be computable
   *
   * TODO: event.session always exists? If type=SESSION, remove undefined checks
   * @see https://developer-docs.com/the-backend/api-changes#dashboardevent-agenda-new
   */
  export interface IAgenda extends ResponseServerEvent<SessionPreview> {
    session_type: SessionType;
    session_length: number;
    ev_start_time: ShortDateTimeWithSpaceDelimiter;
    ev_end_time: ShortDateTimeWithSpaceDelimiter;
    is_editable: boolean;
  }
}
```

With regards to the above actual code, I could for instance like to pass the info that a `SessionFull` is a `BaseEventBlocked` to consumers.

Comment: Is `U` not equivalent to `(A | B | C) & { foo: string }`? `T` is also similar to this.

Comment: You are right and I updated the code to simplify.  But I actually want a way of knowing if x: U|T is an A, if possible, without runtime checks. Of course, assuming that I already know this at some point, I just want to pass it on. Fleshed out the question with actual code

Comment: What's the question? It seems like you are asking two at once here